# How to Show or Hide n'th div when clicking on the n'th link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some set of `<div>...</div>` in one child of a parent. And some set of `<a>click</a>` buttons on other child of the same parent. When I click on the first link of child-2, the first div of the child one have to be displayed.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrvtwpjp/48/) I used.

But, I used class name to show or hide the div. I need the script which can select n'th element automatically.

Code I used is below.

```
$('.box').hide();

$(".click-btn1").on('click', function() {
    $('.box').slideUp('slow');
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().children().children(".box1").slideDown('slow');
});

$(".click-btn2").on('click', function() {
    $('.box').slideUp('slow');
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().children().children(".box2").slideDown('slow');
});

$(".click-btn3").on('click', function() {
    $('.box').slideUp('slow');
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().children().children(".box3").slideDown('slow');
});
```

Comment: check the JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mrvtwpjp/48/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `.index()` can simplify your code a lot:

```
$('.box').hide();

$(".click-btn").on('click', function () {
    $('.box').slideUp('slow');
    var i = $(this).parent().parent().index();
    $('.box').eq(i).slideDown('slow');
});
```

This just figures out which button it is, and then slides the box at that index.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by [index](http://jsfiddle.net/mrvtwpjp/52/) if your DOM elements will be in the same order:

```
$('.box').hide();

$(".click-btn").on('click', function() {
    $('.box').slideUp('slow');
    $('.total-1').children().eq($(this).parents('.single').index()).slideDown('slow');
});
```